# How do I extend a parent state's data in angular ui router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know that I can inherit a parent's data as-is, or overwrite it, but how might I extend it? For example:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
    url: "/parent",
    template: "<div ui-view></div>",
    data: { a: "Hello" }
})
.state('parent.child', {
    url: "/child",
    template: "<p>lorem ipsum</p>",
    data: { a: this.data.a + " World!" } // <-- something like that.
});
```

I need to add on to my parent's data property, but I don't want to copy paste it or replace it entirely.

Comment: FYI. You can access the parent data from the child controller, you don't have to create new data.

Answer (score 0):

There is something that's called scope hierarchy and you don't need to copy/paste your data again.
Here is the link that describe it: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope